# Requests.get module python getting 404-400

Tags: python, url

```
import requests
with open('urls.txt') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        print r.status_code
```

The code has appears to have a problem, the "urls.txt" lines include "http://" and I think because of those the script isn't working because I receive `404` and `400` status codes while the websites are online!  And how can I have the urls appear in terminal next to the status code?

Comment: No, URLs passed to `requests` *must* have the protocol included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to strip the `url`, it includes the newline from the file:

```
import requests
with open('urls.txt') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        url = url.strip()
        r = requests.get(url)
        print url, r.status_code
```

By using `.strip()` you remove whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) from the start and end of the string.

To print the URL with the status code, simply add it to the `print` statement.

Comment: Oooh! Thanks man and another question how can I put comments? For example:
if r.status_code == 200:
   print '[{}]: '.format(url), 'Up!'
  elif r.status_code == 401:
   print '[{}]: '.format(url), 'Up mas protegido!'
  else r.status_code == 404:
   print '[{}]: '.format(url), 'Not found!'

Is like this?

Comment: @user1985563: try it out! Python is easy, but you may want to read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: @user1985563: impossible to tell from your posted comment why it doesn't work. Try things out in the Python interpreter prompt, play around with the language, you'll figure it out.